# Python signxml "ValueError: Could not unserialize key data."

Tags: python, xml-signature

I'm trying Python's [signxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/signxml) library to signing xml and verifying the signature.
But it throws following exception, what could be wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/digz/Documents/test_signxml/xml_verify_test_4.py", line 24, in <module>
    signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\signxml\__init__.py", line 364, in sign
    key = load_pem_private_key(key, password=passphrase, backend=default_backend())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization.py", line 20, in load_pem_private_key
    return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\multibackend.py", line 289, in load_pem_private_key
    return b.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 1033, in load_pem_private_key
    password,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 1202, in _load_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 1274, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError("Could not unserialize key data.")
ValueError: Could not unserialize key data.
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier
from myapp import settings

cert = open(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/file/public.cert', 'rt').read()
key = open(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/file/public.key', 'rt').read()

root = ElementTree.fromstring('<xml1>12</xml1>')
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root).signed_xml
print verified_data
```

Comment: The certificate has to read in binary mode `rb`,